# PHP preg_match_all not working as expecteded

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Here's my code,

```
$msg = "{yellow:red} ERROR:  {blue:light_grey}";
$pattern = "/{(.*)}/";
$a = preg_match_all($pattern, $msg, $regex);
```

I'm expecting the following 2 matches:

```
{yellow:red}
{blue:light_grey}
```

But my result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {yellow:red} ERROR:  {blue:light_grey}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => yellow:red} ERROR:  {blue:light_grey
        )

)
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Keyword - greedy search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change regular to this:

```
{([^}]*)}
```

If you want also include {} then

```
({[^}]*})
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

The regex of your desire should be: `({[^}]*})`.

---

```
$msg = "{yellow:red} ERROR:  {blue:light_grey}";
$pattern = "({[^}]*})";
$a = preg_match_all($pattern, $msg, $regex);
```

---

- `(` - The parantheses captures a group
- `{` - matches the character { literally (case sensitive)
- `[^` - Match a single character not present in the list
- `*` - Matches between zero and unlimited times, in this scenario everything between the given characters.  In this scenario:  `{ }`